# vue-cli-service production build produces too many css bundles files

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, build, vue-cli

in my VueJS (v. 2.6) project i'm using lazy loading modules like this:

`const Home = () => import("./Home.vue");`

The result is that i got as many .js files as pages, which is fine to me!

My problem is that when launching the `vue-cli-service build` in **production mode** i also got plenty of **.css** bundle files (i assume corrisponding to the relative pages too)

[image]

in my vue.config.js there is no configuration at all about that.

how do i avoid this behaviour? why this is not happening in development mode?

Comment: @JaromandaX it's vuejs2, i updated the tag, thanks